# For a martingale $M$, $\lim_{a\to\infty}\lim_{t\to\infty} \mathbf E( M_t; \int_0^t M_s ds > a ) = 0$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Does the following equality right?
\begin{equation}
  \lim_{a\to\infty}\lim_{t\to\infty} \mathbf E\left( M_t; \int_0^t M_s ds > a \right) = 0,
\end{equation}
where $M = \{M_t\}_{t\ge0}$ is a martingale.

Intuitively, I think it is right. Because $\mathbf E(M_t) = \mathbf E(M_0)$ is a finite time-independent constant. And as $a\to\infty$, $\mathbf P(\int_0^t M_s ds > a)$ is expect to vanish.

But I don't know how to prove it rigorously. Can anyone give some hints? Or if the equality does not hold true, some counterexamples will be appreciated. TIA...

---

PS: By $\mathbf E(X;A)$, I mean $\mathbf E(X\mathbf 1_A)$.

---

**EDIT:** As answered by @user159517 through a trivial counterexample, this is wrong in general. However, is there any possibility that it does hold for some non-trivial martingales, say, for example, the exponential martingale which is crucial in the [Girsanov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem)?

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong. Let $M_t \equiv 1$, then $$\mathbb E\left( M_t; \int_0^t M_s ds > a \right) = \mathscr{1}_{[\int_0^t M_s ds > a]} = \mathscr{1}_{[t>a]}$$
It follows that $$   \lim_{a\to\infty}\lim_{t\to\infty} \mathbf E\left( M_t; \int_0^t M_s ds > a \right) = 1.$$

Comment: Oh... Well. Thank you for your counterexample.

Comment: So it seems that the point is the order of limit?

Comment: Does that hold for other non-trivial martingale, like the exponential martingale? See the EDIT in my question. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: I'm responding a bit late here, but 1) Yes, the point is the order of limit, and given that it even fails for something as "nice" as a constant martingale, I don't think you have a great chance of finding an easy general condition that allows you to switch the limits 2) The martingale $M_t \equiv 1$ is the exponential of the zero martingale, so I don't think that restricting to exponential martingales helps.